# filter json response property based on locale query parameter

Tags: javascript, json, functional-programming, ramda.js

I have a json response that i'm getting from an api and mongoDB as following:

I'm passing query Param in the request which I also have access to it in nestjs `app.service.ts` query param `?locale` can be either `en`, `es`, or `de` default one being `en` if no `?locale` is passed in the URL

```
[
    {
        "name": {
            "en": "PLA",
            "de": "PLA",
            "es": "PLA"
        },
        "density": 5.17,
        "id": "32ccfa8d-8db6-41f6-83fa-7726851bffd4",
        "image": "https://test.image/pla",
        "description": {
            "en": "PLA English description",
            "de": "PLA deutsche Beschreibung",
            "es": "PLA descripción en español"
        },
        "finishes": [
            {
                "name": {
                    "en": "Standard",
                    "de": "Standard",
                    "es": "Estándar"
                },
                "materialId": "32ccfa8d-8db6-41f6-83fa-7726851bffd4",
                "colorIds": [
                    "9704a8b0-ae94-4945-94ef-8445b387d48d",
                    "1ba6c1ae-8c41-47f3-b925-11316afd1ddd",
                    "d648994f-b1fa-4982-969e-eee2f7a68c77",
                    "d18cd8a2-e1ab-4de4-bda4-c3610d9fd93e",
                    "e1e78350-4f7e-4d5c-9ebc-5fa3b10e7ce1"
                ],
                "id": "8f529b1f-18a8-408b-a88c-b9056ef6e50e",
                "image": "https://test.image/pla_standard",
                "description": {
                    "en": "PLA Standard English description",
                    "de": "PLA Standard deutsche Beschreibung",
                    "es": "PLA estándar descripción en español"
                },
                "colors": [
                    {
                        "_id": "d18cd8a2-e1ab-4de4-bda4-c3610d9fd93e",
                        "name": {
                            "en": "PLA",
                            "de": "PLA",
                            "es": "PLA"
                        },
                        "hexCode": "#00CC33",
                        "id": "32ccfa8d-8db6-41f6-83fa-7726851bffd4",
                        "image": "https://test.image/pla",
                        "description": {
                            "en": "PLA English description",
                            "de": "PLA deutsche Beschreibung",
                            "es": "PLA descripción en español"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "_id": "1ba6c1ae-8c41-47f3-b925-11316afd1ddd",
                        "name": {
                            "en": "316L Stainless Steel",
                            "de": "316L Rostfreier Stahl",
                            "es": "316L Acero Inoxidable"
                        },
                        "hexCode": "#000000",
                        "id": "c7bc7177-8137-4552-a218-0aa4d2491373",
                        "image": "https://test.image/316L",
                        "description": {
                            "en": "316L English description",
                            "de": "316L deutsche Beschreibung",
                            "es": "316L descripción en español"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "_id": "d648994f-b1fa-4982-969e-eee2f7a68c77",
                        "name": {
                            "en": "MJF Nylon PA12",
                            "de": "MJF Nylon PA12",
                            "es": "MJF Nylon PA12"
                        },
                        "hexCode": "#FF465B",
                        "id": "5857ed97-bc6f-4e30-84c7-864d63fa2ab5",
                        "image": "https://test.image/mjf_nylon",
                        "description": {
                            "en": "MJF Nylon PA12 English description",
                            "de": "MJF Nylon PA12 deutsche Beschreibung",
                            "es": "MJF Nylon PA12 descripción en español"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": {
                    "en": "Polished",
                    "de": "Poliert",
                    "es": "Pulido"
                },
                "materialId": "32ccfa8d-8db6-41f6-83fa-7726851bffd4",
                "colorIds": [
                    "9704a8b0-ae94-4945-94ef-8445b387d48d",
                    "1ba6c1ae-8c41-47f3-b925-11316afd1ddd",
                    "d648994f-b1fa-4982-969e-eee2f7a68c77",
                    "d18cd8a2-e1ab-4de4-bda4-c3610d9fd93e",
                    "e1e78350-4f7e-4d5c-9ebc-5fa3b10e7ce1"
                ],
                "id": "9704a8b0-ae94-4945-94ef-8445b387d48d",
                "image": "https://test.image/mjf_nylon_polished",
                "description": {
                    "en": "MJF Nylon PA12 polished English description",
                    "de": "MJF Nylon PA12 poliert deutsche Beschreibung",
                    "es": "MJF Nylon PA12 pulido descripción en español"
                },
                "colors": [
                    {
                        "_id": "d18cd8a2-e1ab-4de4-bda4-c3610d9fd93e",
                        "name": {
                            "en": "PLA",
                            "de": "PLA",
                            "es": "PLA"
                        },
                        "hexCode": "#00CC33",
                        "id": "32ccfa8d-8db6-41f6-83fa-7726851bffd4",
                        "image": "https://test.image/pla",
                        "description": {
                            "en": "PLA English description",
                            "de": "PLA deutsche Beschreibung",
                            "es": "PLA descripción en español"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "_id": "1ba6c1ae-8c41-47f3-b925-11316afd1ddd",
                        "name": {
                            "en": "316L Stainless Steel",
                            "de": "316L Rostfreier Stahl",
                            "es": "316L Acero Inoxidable"
                        },
                        "hexCode": "#000000",
                        "id": "c7bc7177-8137-4552-a218-0aa4d2491373",
                        "image": "https://test.image/316L",
                        "description": {
                            "en": "316L English description",
                            "de": "316L deutsche Beschreibung",
                            "es": "316L descripción en español"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "_id": "d648994f-b1fa-4982-969e-eee2f7a68c77",
                        "name": {
                            "en": "MJF Nylon PA12",
                            "de": "MJF Nylon PA12",
                            "es": "MJF Nylon PA12"
                        },
                        "hexCode": "#FF465B",
                        "id": "5857ed97-bc6f-4e30-84c7-864d63fa2ab5",
                        "image": "https://test.image/mjf_nylon",
                        "description": {
                            "en": "MJF Nylon PA12 English description",
                            "de": "MJF Nylon PA12 deutsche Beschreibung",
                            "es": "MJF Nylon PA12 descripción en español"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }...]
```

what I would like to do is get the following parsed json ideally by ramdajs but vanillaJS should also work:

```
{
  "materials": [
    {
      "id": "8b4c3e04-beb1-40b4-885a-bba33300d14e",
      "name": "PLA",
      "image": "https://test.image/pla",
      "density": 1.2,
      "finishes": [
        {
          "id": "04eb376d-0790-4c41-a45f-164fb0414892",
          "name": "Standard",
          "image": "https://image/pla_standard",
          "description": "PLA description",
          "colors": [{
            "id": "78bd5280-9199-414c-b0fd-df01f18807e1",
            "name": "White",
            "hexCode": "#FFFFFF"
          },
          {
            "id": "78bd5280-9199-414c-b0fd-df01f18807e1",
            "name": "Black",
            "hexCode": "#000000"
          }]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I am parsing the current response like this:

```
    const catalog = (parsedMaterials) => (parsedFinishes) => (parsedColors) =>
      parsedMaterials.map((material) => ({
        ...material,
        finishes: parsedFinishes
          .filter((finish) => {
            return finish.materialId == material.id;
          })
          .map((finish) => ({
            ...finish,
            colors: parsedColors.filter((color) => {
              return finish.colorIds.includes(color._id);
            }),
          })),
      }));
```

**Update:**

a comment asked how I'm getting the above mapped through variables:

I'm fetching responses from both a mongoDB source and a Rest-api, i'm chaining the promises and then storing the results in the above mentioned variables after merging them.

```
    const getMaterials = () =>
      Promise.all([
        getMongoDBMaterials(this.materialsRepository),
        getCMSMaterials(),
      ]).then(R.apply(R.zipWith(R.mergeRight)));

    const getFinishes = () =>
      Promise.all([
        getMongoDBFinishes(this.finishesRepository),
        getCMSFinishes(),
      ]).then(R.apply(R.zipWith(R.mergeRight)));

    const getColors = () =>
      Promise.all([
        getMongoDBColors(this.colorsRepository),
        getCMSColors(),
      ]).then(R.apply(R.zipWith(R.mergeRight)));

    const parsedMaterials = await getMaterials()
      .then((data) => {
        return data;
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(`Error: ${err}`));

    const parsedColors = await getColors()
      .then((data) => {
        return data;
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(`Error: ${err}`));

    const parsedFinishes = await getFinishes()
      .then((data) => {
        return data;
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(`Error: ${err}`));
```

Thank you

Comment: How have you tried to solve this yourself?  The code you show is not designed for this input structure, depending on three separate inputs for materials, finishes, and colors, instead of the nested structure you show.  And it does not attempt to handle the language parameter at all.  Have you started on this?  Did it fail somewhere?

Comment: Also, how would you handle colors where the id is not included in the list of full colors?

Comment: I've added an update where it could hopefully clear some doubts, i haven't started on filtering according to `locale` because i don't know whether to handle it where I'm merging the two objects or where i'm mapping through the responses ?

Comment: the missing color Ids are essentially there in the initial response coming back from mongoDB, AFAICS our mergeRight is not working as intended. i already have an active question to which i'm going to get back to to solve that issue. for now I believe if I could have a slight glimpse as to how to handle the filter by `locale` i should be able to produce the desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a suggestion for the locale handling, based on the input and output structure you suggest.  It does not try to do anything with the rest of the restructuring.

It is based on a somewhat flexible function that looks deeply for properties (and sub-properties, and sub-sub-properties, etc.) with certain keys, and replaces them by looking up the value for a given fixed key (here your language parameter.)

It might look like this:

```js
const chooseNestedProps = (props) => (val) => (obj) => 
  Array .isArray (obj)
    ? obj .map (chooseNestedProps (props) (val))
  : Object (obj) === obj 
    ? Object .fromEntries (Object .entries (obj) .map (([k, v]) => 
      [k, props .includes (k) ? v [val] : chooseNestedProps (props) (val) (v)]
    ))
  : obj

const input = [{name: {en: "PLA", de: "PLA", es: "PLA"}, density: 5.17, id: "32ccfa8d-8db6-41f6-83fa-7726851bffd4", image: "https: //test.image/pla", description: {en: "PLA English description", de: "PLA deutsche Beschreibung", es: "PLA descripción en español"}, finishes: [{name: {en: "Standard", de: "Standard", es: "Estándar"}, materialId: "32ccfa8d-8db6-41f6-83fa-7726851bffd4", colorIds: ["9704a8b0-ae94-4945-94ef-8445b387d48d", "1ba6c1ae-8c41-47f3-b925-11316afd1ddd", "d648994f-b1fa-4982-969e-eee2f7a68c77", "d18cd8a2-e1ab-4de4-bda4-c3610d9fd93e", "e1e78350-4f7e-4d5c-9ebc-5fa3b10e7ce1"], id: "8f529b1f-18a8-408b-a88c-b9056ef6e50e", image: "https: //test.image/pla_standard", description: {en: "PLA Standard English description", de: "PLA Standard deutsche Beschreibung", es: "PLA estándar descripción en español"}, colors: [{_id: "d18cd8a2-e1ab-4de4-bda4-c3610d9fd93e", name: {en: "PLA", de: "PLA", es: "PLA"}, hexCode: "#00CC33", id: "32ccfa8d-8db6-41f6-83fa-7726851bffd4", image: "https: //test.image/pla", description: {en: "PLA English description", de: "PLA deutsche Beschreibung", es: "PLA descripción en español"}}, {_id: "1ba6c1ae-8c41-47f3-b925-11316afd1ddd", name: {en: "316L Stainless Steel", de: "316L Rostfreier Stahl", es: "316L Acero Inoxidable"}, hexCode: "#000000", id: "c7bc7177-8137-4552-a218-0aa4d2491373", image: "https: //test.image/316L", description: {en: "316L English description", de: "316L deutsche Beschreibung", es: "316L descripción en español"}}, {_id: "d648994f-b1fa-4982-969e-eee2f7a68c77", name: {en: "MJF Nylon PA12", de: "MJF Nylon PA12", es: "MJF Nylon PA12"}, hexCode: "#FF465B", id: "5857ed97-bc6f-4e30-84c7-864d63fa2ab5", image: "https: //test.image/mjf_nylon", description: {en: "MJF Nylon PA12 English description", de: "MJF Nylon PA12 deutsche Beschreibung", es: "MJF Nylon PA12 descripción en español"}}]}, {name: {en: "Polished", de: "Poliert", es: "Pulido"}, materialId: "32ccfa8d-8db6-41f6-83fa-7726851bffd4", colorIds: ["9704a8b0-ae94-4945-94ef-8445b387d48d", "1ba6c1ae-8c41-47f3-b925-11316afd1ddd", "d648994f-b1fa-4982-969e-eee2f7a68c77", "d18cd8a2-e1ab-4de4-bda4-c3610d9fd93e", "e1e78350-4f7e-4d5c-9ebc-5fa3b10e7ce1"], id: "9704a8b0-ae94-4945-94ef-8445b387d48d", image: "https: //test.image/mjf_nylon_polished", description: {en: "MJF Nylon PA12 polished English description", de: "MJF Nylon PA12 poliert deutsche Beschreibung", es: "MJF Nylon PA12 pulido descripción en español"}, colors: [{_id: "d18cd8a2-e1ab-4de4-bda4-c3610d9fd93e", name: {en: "PLA", de: "PLA", es: "PLA"}, hexCode: "#00CC33", id: "32ccfa8d-8db6-41f6-83fa-7726851bffd4", image: "https: //test.image/pla", description: {en: "PLA English description", de: "PLA deutsche Beschreibung", es: "PLA descripción en español"}}, {_id: "1ba6c1ae-8c41-47f3-b925-11316afd1ddd", name: {en: "316L Stainless Steel", de: "316L Rostfreier Stahl", es: "316L Acero Inoxidable"}, hexCode: "#000000", id: "c7bc7177-8137-4552-a218-0aa4d2491373", image: "https: //test.image/316L", description: {en: "316L English description", de: "316L deutsche Beschreibung", es: "316L descripción en español"}}, {_id: "d648994f-b1fa-4982-969e-eee2f7a68c77", name: {en: "MJF Nylon PA12", de: "MJF Nylon PA12", es: "MJF Nylon PA12"}, hexCode: "#FF465B", id: "5857ed97-bc6f-4e30-84c7-864d63fa2ab5", image: "https: //test.image/mjf_nylon", description: {en: "MJF Nylon PA12 English description", de: "MJF Nylon PA12 deutsche Beschreibung", es: "MJF Nylon PA12 descripción en español"}}]}]}]


console .log (chooseNestedProps (['name', 'description']) ('en') (input))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

But I would actually rather abstract that a bit, and use a still more general function that allows us to set the nested values of an object by passing two functions: a predicate which tests if this key/value combination *should* be replaces, and a tranformer that returns a new value when supplied a key and value.  Then we can write `chooseNestedProps` more simply atop that reusable function, something like this:

```js
const deepMap = (pred, fn) => (o) =>
  Array .isArray (o)
    ? o .map (x => deepMap (pred, fn) (x))
  : Object (o) === o
    ? Object .fromEntries (Object .entries (o) .map (
        ([k, v]) => [k, pred (k, v) ? fn (k, v) : deepMap (pred, fn)(v)]
      ))
  : o

const chooseNestedProps = (props) => (val) => deepMap (
  (k, v) => props .includes (k), 
  (k, v) => v [val]
)
    

const input = [{name: {en: "PLA", de: "PLA", es: "PLA"}, density: 5.17, id: "32ccfa8d-8db6-41f6-83fa-7726851bffd4", image: "https: //test.image/pla", description: {en: "PLA English description", de: "PLA deutsche Beschreibung", es: "PLA descripción en español"}, finishes: [{name: {en: "Standard", de: "Standard", es: "Estándar"}, materialId: "32ccfa8d-8db6-41f6-83fa-7726851bffd4", colorIds: ["9704a8b0-ae94-4945-94ef-8445b387d48d", "1ba6c1ae-8c41-47f3-b925-11316afd1ddd", "d648994f-b1fa-4982-969e-eee2f7a68c77", "d18cd8a2-e1ab-4de4-bda4-c3610d9fd93e", "e1e78350-4f7e-4d5c-9ebc-5fa3b10e7ce1"], id: "8f529b1f-18a8-408b-a88c-b9056ef6e50e", image: "https: //test.image/pla_standard", description: {en: "PLA Standard English description", de: "PLA Standard deutsche Beschreibung", es: "PLA estándar descripción en español"}, colors: [{_id: "d18cd8a2-e1ab-4de4-bda4-c3610d9fd93e", name: {en: "PLA", de: "PLA", es: "PLA"}, hexCode: "#00CC33", id: "32ccfa8d-8db6-41f6-83fa-7726851bffd4", image: "https: //test.image/pla", description: {en: "PLA English description", de: "PLA deutsche Beschreibung", es: "PLA descripción en español"}}, {_id: "1ba6c1ae-8c41-47f3-b925-11316afd1ddd", name: {en: "316L Stainless Steel", de: "316L Rostfreier Stahl", es: "316L Acero Inoxidable"}, hexCode: "#000000", id: "c7bc7177-8137-4552-a218-0aa4d2491373", image: "https: //test.image/316L", description: {en: "316L English description", de: "316L deutsche Beschreibung", es: "316L descripción en español"}}, {_id: "d648994f-b1fa-4982-969e-eee2f7a68c77", name: {en: "MJF Nylon PA12", de: "MJF Nylon PA12", es: "MJF Nylon PA12"}, hexCode: "#FF465B", id: "5857ed97-bc6f-4e30-84c7-864d63fa2ab5", image: "https: //test.image/mjf_nylon", description: {en: "MJF Nylon PA12 English description", de: "MJF Nylon PA12 deutsche Beschreibung", es: "MJF Nylon PA12 descripción en español"}}]}, {name: {en: "Polished", de: "Poliert", es: "Pulido"}, materialId: "32ccfa8d-8db6-41f6-83fa-7726851bffd4", colorIds: ["9704a8b0-ae94-4945-94ef-8445b387d48d", "1ba6c1ae-8c41-47f3-b925-11316afd1ddd", "d648994f-b1fa-4982-969e-eee2f7a68c77", "d18cd8a2-e1ab-4de4-bda4-c3610d9fd93e", "e1e78350-4f7e-4d5c-9ebc-5fa3b10e7ce1"], id: "9704a8b0-ae94-4945-94ef-8445b387d48d", image: "https: //test.image/mjf_nylon_polished", description: {en: "MJF Nylon PA12 polished English description", de: "MJF Nylon PA12 poliert deutsche Beschreibung", es: "MJF Nylon PA12 pulido descripción en español"}, colors: [{_id: "d18cd8a2-e1ab-4de4-bda4-c3610d9fd93e", name: {en: "PLA", de: "PLA", es: "PLA"}, hexCode: "#00CC33", id: "32ccfa8d-8db6-41f6-83fa-7726851bffd4", image: "https: //test.image/pla", description: {en: "PLA English description", de: "PLA deutsche Beschreibung", es: "PLA descripción en español"}}, {_id: "1ba6c1ae-8c41-47f3-b925-11316afd1ddd", name: {en: "316L Stainless Steel", de: "316L Rostfreier Stahl", es: "316L Acero Inoxidable"}, hexCode: "#000000", id: "c7bc7177-8137-4552-a218-0aa4d2491373", image: "https: //test.image/316L", description: {en: "316L English description", de: "316L deutsche Beschreibung", es: "316L descripción en español"}}, {_id: "d648994f-b1fa-4982-969e-eee2f7a68c77", name: {en: "MJF Nylon PA12", de: "MJF Nylon PA12", es: "MJF Nylon PA12"}, hexCode: "#FF465B", id: "5857ed97-bc6f-4e30-84c7-864d63fa2ab5", image: "https: //test.image/mjf_nylon", description: {en: "MJF Nylon PA12 English description", de: "MJF Nylon PA12 deutsche Beschreibung", es: "MJF Nylon PA12 descripción en español"}}]}]}]


console .log (chooseNestedProps (['name', 'description']) ('en') (input))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

This does not use Ramda.  Ramda is not particularly suited to building full recursive functions, although you could certainly use it in the implementation, replacing things like `Array .isArray (obj)` and `Object (obj) === obj` with `is (Array)` and `is (Object)`, replacing `Object .fromEntries` and `Object .entries` with `fromPairs` and `toPairs`, and using `map` and `includes` instead of their `Array .prototype` versions.  But I don't think that would clarify much.

Of course we could also write a more specific solution to your problem to as a reusable function, with something like

```js
const chooseLanguage = (o, lang) => chooseNestedProps (['name', 'description']) (lang) (o)

// later
chooseLanguage (input, 'es')
```